# How to achieve same CIFilter effect on multiple sizes of same image

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

Due to performance issues I need to filter first small image and after that higher resolution image.

[image]

I'm using CICrystallize filter and I can't achieve same results for different images resolutions. I'm trying something like this to change input radius value depending on the image size:

```
let radiusValue = image.size.width / 15.0
filter.setValue(radiusValue, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
```

but result is not valid as shown on picture.

Comment: Do you even get the same result twice in a row on the same image?

Comment: Yes, I get exactly the same results twice in a row on the same image

Comment: I wonder if there is a maximum radius value for this effect?

Comment: There is no maximum radius value for this effect, but at some point if radius value is too large you get black image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly mean that small. (Resize?/Crop?)

What about this way? if the image and small image are the same aspects, you can get a good result.

```
let ratio  = smallImage.size.width / originalSizeImage.size.width
let radius = 30

filter.setValue(radius * ratio, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
let inputSizeFactor = min(inputImage.size.width, inputImage.size.height) / 1000
let scaledRadius = radius * inputSizeFactor
filter.setValue(scaledRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
```

it's work because

> The radius determines how many pixels are used to create the effect.
>   The larger the radius, the larger the resulting crystals.

---

Thank you @FrankSchlegel